# How to increment rows each time an Excel VBA Macro is run

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have recorded a macro to get a filtered set of 6 numbers and paste them in row 1.I want to get another set of 6 numbers in row 2 when I next run the macro and a third set in row three and so on when I run it for the third time and so on.how to do it?

Comment: What exactly you want? just rerunning a macro ?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the filtering, do a check to see if there is any data in the row, and increment if there is. Something like:

```
If Range("A1") <> vbNullString Then
   cell.Offset(1,0)
```

should do it (I don't have excel in front of me, atm).